# Smoke not showing up in render but shows up in materials (I'm using my cpu)

Tags: cycles-render-engine, smoke-simulation

As you can see it works perfectly fine in materials[image]

But in rendered view and in render nothing shows up
[image][image]

Answer (score 0):

The problem was that the mesh that I used was colored and not transparent and that caused problems beacuse I set temp. diff in domain to 0